# How are these remote/headless display dongles used?

Tags: wireless-networking, multiple-monitors, remote-access, dongle, display-adapter

I have a "dumb" TV in one room, and a PC in another room. It's been suggested to me I might want to get a "display emulator" dongle, which will somehow let my PC believe it is feeding a regular display (e.g. DisplayPort as in [this Fueran device](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32815684903.html)), while actually, the TV monitor will be used.

But something is missing in this rosy picture: What exactly gets connected on the TV end? Is it a second, identical, device? Is it a different, receiver unit? And how do I control which receiver the transmitter pairs with, if there are no controls on the device, and the PC only sees it as a display?

I'm sure I'm missing something here.

[image: Fueran display port dongle.]

Comment: there is no `TV end` ... the device is not a transmitter ... it makes the PC "think" that a monitor is connected, so that the PC can run headless

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**tl;dr: These dongles don't transmit anything to a remote display, you need another device to send the PC display signal to your "dumb" TV.**

The emulator is only necessary as some (most?) PC's refuse to start "headless", i.e. without a display connected via a cable. The emulator does nothing in terms of signal transmission, it just allows your computer to boot without a connected display as it "tricks" your PC in thinking there is a display attached.

To get your TV to show what your PC is sending, you'll need some kind of wireless receiver plugged into the TV HDMI port. There are plenty of different options, the most famous (and data hungry) probably being the Google Chromecast. [This article](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-use-your-tv-as-an-extended-monitor-without-casting/) lists a few other options, such as:

- Wireless HDMI transmitter/receiver (in that case you wouldn't need the emulator)
- Roku TV or Amazon Fire
- Using a spare laptop connected to the TV as a wireless Miracast receiver

Comment: @doneal24 Many folks use Mac minis as servers and they have HDMI ports. So an HDMI port dongle makes sense in the case of a Mac mini.

Comment: I would need things which: 1. Work on Linux and 2. Can be trusted not to spy on me and phone home (or wherever). So, nothing by Amazon nor Google please.

Comment: So, what do they call dongles which _do_ transmit the HDMI or DP output to a remote receiver?

Answer (score 23):

### Display dongles like these trick the PC into believing an actual display is connected to the display port.

#### The benefit depends totally on use.

It’s not magic; it just effectively “shorts” connections in the display port connector with either a resistor or two (for analog displays) or some kind of simple EPROM or IC (for digital displays) to make the port think an actual display is connected.

I am only familiar with it’s use as described here on [Other World Computing’s website](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/ADP4KHEAD/). I used one of these on a headless Mac mini server.

Without the adapter connected, I could only get specific (and small size) resolutions on my remote desktop session. But when I plugged in one of these things, it tricked the Mac mini into believing a larger, full resolution display was connected which allowed me to view things on a larger desktop.

This description from the Other World Computing page for this dongle explains it well:

> “Remote accessing these machines used to mean being limited to viewing a hard to view, low resolution screen…even if you used an older monitor connected to the remote machine. With the NewerTech HDMI Headless 4K Display Emulator, you can now break free of limited 1024 x 768 or 1280 x 1024 resolution headaches when accessing macOS, Windows, and Linux machines remotely while viewing the desktop with up to full 4K 4096 x 2160 resolution.”

So when I used a dongle like this and remoted into the Mac mini that was being used as a server, the desktop display I would see on my Remote Desktop connection was larger.

And yes, a headless server technically doesn’t need a high resolution display. But in my experience, the GPU on a Mac mini doesn’t kick in unless some physical display — or this kind of dongle — is attached. Without the GPU rendering the display image, maneuvering around the desktop while remoted in is painful at best. Oftentimes you can literally see the screen redraw itself as you moved your mouse around or generally interacted with the desktop.

As further explained on the Other World Computing page for this dongle; bold emphasis is mine:

> “But, trying to use those apps remotely on a headless machine running OSX 10.12.x (Sierra) and earlier can cause choppy images and mouse lags **because the GPU isn’t activated in those OS versions. Plugging the NewerTech HDMI Headless 4K Display Emulator into an open HDMI interface on your machine is the solution to eliminate hampered performance and a small desktop**.”

So using a dongle like this has a clear benefit for a headless PC.

#### But does this mean anything for a PC connecting to a so-called “dumb” TV? Unclear how a dongle like this would help.

As for the benefit of using it on a PC that is connected to a “dumb” TV? Unclear on what that would do. Maybe the idea is to force the dumb TV to have a higher resolution? Not too sure how that would work.

I believe the idea might be that if you connect a “dumb” TV to a PC, the display will only use safe (aka: low resolution) options to display an image on the screen. But somehow the assumption is if you plug this into the display port on your PC it will force the PC into using a higher resolution for the TV?

To me that would assume your PC has two display ports: One connected to the “dumb” TV and one with this dongle in it. And the GPU would then go, “Well, I guess I don’t know what this ‘dumb’ TV is, so I will default to the image on this other display that is connected; aka: the dongle.”

But that seems more like a “hunch” than a hard and fast rule. This kind of dongle is not a “one size fits all” thing. It is useful for very specific usage cases. It’s not magic.

Comment: Love the explanation, makes loads of sense to me. Initially arrived from this question - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445494/accessing-macbookpro-single-screen-remotely-from-a-thin-client-with-two-scre - how I have a solution!

Comment: The same trick related to GPU activation is also true on Windows and with DisplayLink adapters. After a laptop developed a display issue which wasn't resolved with a panel replacement, such a dongle was necessary to trick the OS into using the GPU when rendering to the external USB display (which was now the only display)

Comment: I'm surprised they mention a Linux benefit.  You can just run a pure software X server of any resolution, like Xvnc that you can remote connect to over a higher-latency connection.  I guess that wouldn't necessarily let you use the GPU on the headless machine, but even then you can probably xrandr your display resolution even without a monitor connected if you can run an X server that uses the GPU at all.  Or configure it with a modeline in an xorg.conf.  I guess having a dongle show up as a high-resolution monitor would make that happen without having to edit a config file; go marketing :P

Comment: Its also useful with some remote desktop software that expect a 'real' monitor - I use them for parsec or nomachine, both of which need it or an actual monitor to work

Answer (score 7):

I use the HDMI version of this ... pretty much daily. There's a [teardown of this here](https://goughlui.com/2019/06/02/review-teardown-generic-hdmi-cheater-dummy-plug-4k-uhd/), and its literally a chip that outputs the [EDID information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) of a hypothetical monitor.

I believe folks used to use similar devices at one point to enable quick sync on intel integrated graphics - the driver wouldn't let you unless a monitor was plugged in.

Its also useful for remote access software the 'expects' a monitor plugged in -  [parsec recommends it as a workaround](https://support.parsec.app/hc/en-us/articles/115002683491-Running-Parsec-On-A-Headless-Gaming-PC-Or-A-Server), and I use it with nomachine on linux as well.

There *are* devices like the chromecast and some miracast dongles that'll take in a signal via wireless connection for your  TV but these tend to need an additional USB connection for power.